# How to convert 1 Cr to 10000000 in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formatting, format, dataset

I have a dataset column with following value
1.01 Cr
20.5 L
2.51 Cr
3.16 Cr
1.68 L
.
.
and so on

(1 Cr = 10000000, 1 L = 100000)

how do I unformat this number for example, 1.01 Cr to 10100000 and 20.5 L to 2050000
I refered this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuqBhwzWqBU&ab_channel=JigneshGupta
and tried *=IFNA(LEFT(C2,LEN(C2)-1)*CHOOSE(MATCH(RIGHT(C2,1),{"L","Cr"},0),100000,10000000),C2)**
but its not working.
I know nothing about excel let me know that formula should I use?

[Dataset sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4u7E.png)
refer this img for sample view

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula you are using looks to the last character in the string.
CR is two characters and as such you will never match.  Instead, split on the space:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)*CHOOSE(MATCH(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)),{"L","Cr"},0),100000,10000000)
```

[image]

With the newer functions currently being released we can use TEXTBEFORE and TEXTAFTER instead:

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1," ")*CHOOSE(MATCH(TEXTAFTER(A1," "),{"L","Cr"},0),100000,10000000)
```

Comment: @SachinChoudhary please consider marking the one you ended up using as the correct one by clicking the check mark by the answer you used.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
=LET(X,TEXTBEFORE(A1," ")*100000,IF(RIGHT(A1)="r",X*100,X))
```

---

Or a variation that would make spilling easier (thanks @ScottCraner):

```
=LET(x,A1:A5,TEXTBEFORE(x," ")*10^(5+2*(RIGHT(x)="r")))
```

Comment: `=let(x,A1,TEXTBEFORE(x," ")*100000*10^((RIGHT(x)="r")*2))`?

Comment: Even smoother. You'd be a fine [Code-Golfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) @ScottCraner. This saves 1 byte :)

Comment: also easier to spill: `=let(x,A1:A5,TEXTBEFORE(x," ")*100000*10^((RIGHT(x)="r")*2))`

Comment: As to Golf. I do not need another rabbit hole to fall into.  :)  I already spend too much time here.

Comment: I started a week or so ago. It makes for some very interesting intellectual challenges and it's rewarding at the same time. Yes.....it's a rabbit hole @ScottCraner =)